# how to create empty array?

Tags: json, boost, boost-propertytree

It's possible to get following output from boost::property_tree::json_parser::write_json

```
{
  "id": "id",
  "method": "test_method",
  "params": []
}
```

I know how to create array with some items, but when I try to create empty array, I've get "params": ""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've asked about this issue in boost's mail-list. In general: it's not possible, because json is typed, but property-tree isn't.
http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2011/03/66911.php